# Are they buffalos? No, they're something slightly different

Tags: number-sequence, computer-science

Given the numeric sequence:

344865 78930 136275 152340

Is the next number in the sequence:

a) 82770 b) 340545 c) 271125 d) 75060

The title is, as always, a hint.  Here's another:

> The data I have provided is mostly red herrings.  Part of the puzzle is to figure out what information is not a red herring.

EDIT: Changed the numbers so the pattern is a bit more noticeable.

EDIT 2: Added computer-science tag, which is also a clue.

Comment: Hmmm, I'm afraid your puzzle is too broad, as it is presently expressed. If the data is mostly red-herrings, then anyone can pick whatever suits their reasoning and ignore whatever contradicts it. By conveniently choosing what is a red herring and what is not, I can quickly end up with two equally valid answers. For example, the first digit is always odd, and the last one alternates between 0 and 5 => next number is b); or the last hexadecimal digit is 1, 2, 3, 4 so the next number is c).

Comment: @xhienne One of the possibilities you suggested is actually the correct answer.  I suggest you figure out which one it is and submit it :p (Hint as to which one it is: The title is a clue.  Figure out from the title what the intended clue is, I'll be looking for that when I decide to accept your answer)

Comment: I can hardly propose an answer while at the same time flagging your question as "too broad". Those was only two examples of answers, which I considered too simple to be the expected ones (sorry all for the spoiler), and I could have come up with other seemingly valid a) and d) answers too. As for the clue in the title, you have just accepted an answer that saw it as an allusion to "bison", so I could have stated it was a hint that the answer is b) (initial letter). This is what I consider "too broad", see the [relevant discussion on meta](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4573/32339).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Picking up from the answers in the comments, I think the answer is

> C) 271125

The hint from the title is they're not buffalos,

> They're *bison*, a type of parser in C

I think this means that

> we need to convert each number to hexadecimal, because [hex numbers are often used for storage in C](https://www.quora.com/Why-do-we-use-the-hex-number-in-C-language-Why-dont-we-use-a-direct-number#).

Doing this, the first four numbers in the sequence become

> 54321, 13452, 21453, and 25314. These are all arrangements of the digits 1,2,3,4,5; where the final digit increases by one each time. We are therefore looking for a number which, when converted to hex, has the digits 1,2,3,4,5 and the final digit of 5.

We see that

> a) 82770 -> 14352 b) 340545 -> 53241 c) 271125 -> 42315 d) 75060 -> 12534

and so the only one that matches our criteria above is

> C) 271125

Comment: You got the wrong large 4-legged field animal, but otherwise correct.  The animal I was looking for was "ox" (or "oxen"), because Hex numbers in computer science are annotated by adding 0x to the start of them.

Comment: Thanks! Good question. I thought bison was a bit of a stretch (I certainly didn't know it was a parser in C before research), but I quite like the ox-0x connection!

Comment: Also, just as a side note, the arrangement of 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 was just an easy way for me to generate numbers with relative ease such that I could reasonably determine that the leading digits were chosen effectively "at random" so as not to pollute the pattern (that the units digits was uniform-increasing).  I was afraid that if I chose completely random numbers that I would accidentally induce an additional pattern which would pollute the question.

Comment: That's fair, for future, it might have helped to include all digits in the sequence formation (ie. if the first number is 54321, then what could follow are conversions of 15432, 21543, 32154, 43215, or something to that effect). This could eliminate some of the noise/red herrings that you were afraid of, and I don't think it would have made the sequence any easier to solve either. (Incidentally, doing that might have given the puzzle a unique solution where you wouldn't need to restrict the solution set to only 4 choices. Again, great puzzle! I really enjoyed it.

Comment: I actually wanted the noise; I intended part of the challenge to be that the solver would see the numbers and have to intentionally determine that the leading digits were all noise and the only digit that mattered was the units digit.  That was a feature, not a bug :)

Comment: Fair enough! Good feature, then! It added a new layer of complexity! :)